# Skew Laurent Series

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, power-series, laurent-series

I read T. Y. Lam's, "A First Course in Noncommutative Rings" because I want to know an example of a division ring other than the quaternions. I read examples (1.5) and (1.6).

(1.5) I don't understand why $F=f_0+f_1+f_2+\ldots \in U(R)$ implies the constant term $f_0$ is a unit in $k$.

(1.6) Why do they do that for show that $ k ((x)) $ is division ring (take $F\cdot x^i$) ?

Thank you.

Comment: It will severely limit the number of people who can or will answer if the question can't be understood without looking at the textbook. It would be helpful to include what's there so the question can be self-contained.

Comment: Long story short, any noncommutative right Noetherian domain has a division ring of (right) fractions.  The skew construction is just an easy way to build noncommutative domains